# How to draw rectangle in existing pdf with mouse

Tags: c#

I don't know if what I write are right or not and this what I had try:

```
private void pdf_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    PdfLoadedDocument load = new PdfLoadedDocument(@"C:\Users\Afiqah\Downloads\17DDT17F1016.pdf");
    PdfLoadedPage page = load.Pages[0] as PdfLoadedPage;
    PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;
    graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rec);
}

private void pdf_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        rec = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MDown = e.Location;
    }
}

private void pdf_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        rec.Width = e.X - rec.X;
        rec.Height = e.Y - rec.Y;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        rec.Location = new Point((e.X - MDown.X) + rec.Left, (e.Y - MDown.Y) + rec.Top);
        MDown = e.Location;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: If that is syncfusion do add the tag!